# How to replace the enumeration of several annotations with one annotation?

Tags: kotlin, annotations

I have several annotations (`@IdsUniquenessValidation` and `@IdsSufficiencyValidation`) for validation. And now it works ok. But I would like to create some annotations, that will include my already existing annotations, and then I will not need to list them all, but it will simply be enough to write a single one, including the rest that I need.

What I mean is that instead of code listing all the annotations, all I need to do is write code with one annotation `@IdsValidation`, like this:

```kotlin
data class UpsertDataCommand(
    @IdsValidation
    val data: List<Book>,
)
```

I tried such code, but it does not work:

```
@IdsUniquenessValidation
@IdsSufficiencyValidation
annotation class IdsValidation
```

---

My code with listing all the annotations:

```kotlin
data class UpsertDataCommand(
    @IdsUniquenessValidation
    @IdsSufficiencyValidation
    val data: List<Book>,
)
```

My annotations code:

```kotlin
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [IdsUniquenessValidator::class])
annotation class IdsUniquenessValidation(
    val message: String = "{data.ids-uniqueness}",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

```kotlin
@MustBeDocumented
@Retention(AnnotationRetention.RUNTIME)
@Target(AnnotationTarget.FIELD, AnnotationTarget.ANNOTATION_CLASS)
@Constraint(validatedBy = [IdsSufficiencyValidator::class])
annotation class IdsSufficiencyValidation(
    val message: String = "{data.ids-sufficiency}",
    val groups: Array<KClass<*>> = [],
    val payload: Array<KClass<out Payload>> = []
)
```

Comment: You will have to write an annotation processor. See [here](https://proandroiddev.com/the-guide-to-your-first-annotation-processor-with-ksp-and-becoming-a-kotlin-artist-4e5d13f171e6) for a starting point. This might be a bit overkill for what you are trying to do here, but that's how annotations are supposed to be processed.